# Unable to run application in Android over version 3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I use a XML parser for data in my app, but I can't run it in Android over version 3. This is the message in my device when I use Android version 4.0.3: "*Unfortunately, myApp has stopped*". No message in LogCat error.

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news);


    activity = this;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    xmlParser parser = new xmlParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
```

Comment: Please provide logcat error.

Comment: post the relevant code and the related stack trace

Comment: No message in logcat error

Comment: post the code you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change minimum and target sdk version like this

```
 <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```